# Plotting integral solution with varying parameter

Tags: python, plot, numerical-integration

I know there's similar questions around here but none of them get to the root of my problem.

I have an integral which contains a parameter which I want to produce a plot against.

My code is

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy import integrate


def intyfun(x, a):
    return np.exp(-a/4)*np.exp(-x**2*a)*(2*np.pi*x)*(np.sinh(np.pi)/np.cosh(np.pi*x)**2)
```

Now I'm stuck. I want integrate this function for x over 0 to infinity, and plot the value of it as a varies on the x axis as a parameter. How can I do this?

In mathematica I can do this and the plot looks like this

[image]

My mathematica code is

```
integral[a_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Exp[-a/4]*Exp[-mu^2*a]*(2*Pi*mu*Sinh[mu*Pi])/(Cosh[mu*Pi]^2), {mu, 
   0, Infinity}, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, 
    "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000, "SingularityHandler" -> "IMT"}, 
  MaxRecursion -> 100, PrecisionGoal -> 4]

Plot[integral[a], {a, 0.01, 10}, ImageSize -> Large, 
 FrameStyle -> Black,
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"}, PlotLabel -> "", 
 PlotStyle -> Black, FrameStyle -> Black,
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {a, IntegralValue}]
```

if that helps.

N.B mu=x in my python code.

Comment: show expected result of plot, or plot example similar to you expectations

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi I have updated. Hopefully it is clear now.

Comment: and you need to plot colored field below function line that will display integration value?

Comment: No. The y axes on my plot is the value of the integrated for each value of a. I just want to recreate this plot in python.

Comment: I have added my mathematica code so this is easy to see @ZarakiKenpachi

Comment: I've added my code in mathematica so this is easy to see @ZarakiKenpachi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate


def function(x, a):
    return np.exp(-a/4)*np.exp(-x**2*a)*(2*np.pi*x)*(np.sinh(np.pi)/np.cosh(np.pi*x)**2)


def integrate_function(x_min, x_max, a):
    return integrate.quad(function, x_min, x_max, args=(a,))[0]


# define integration range
x_min = 0
x_max = 1
# define range of a variable
a_points = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)

results = []
for a in a_points:
    value = integrate_function(x_min, x_max, a)
    results.append(value)


plt.plot(a_points, results)
plt.ylabel("Integral value")
plt.xlabel("a variable")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. That works great. I made a small error in the function. There should be an x inside the argument of the sinh function. They match up very well now.

Comment: This only integrates between 0 and 1 when it should be 0 and infty. For small `a`, the error is significant.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to avoid the explicit loop, you can use [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (a project of mine) to compute all values in one vectorized integration step. This is *much* faster:

```
import quadpy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


a = np.linspace(0.0, 10.0, 300)


def intyfun(x):
    return (
        np.exp(-a / 4)[:, None]
        * np.exp(np.multiply.outer(a, -(x ** 2)))
        * (2 * np.pi * x)
        * (np.sinh(np.pi) / np.cosh(np.pi * x) ** 2)
    )


val, _ = quadpy.quad(intyfun, 0, np.inf)

plt.plot(a, val)
plt.grid()
plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()
```

[image]